# Which one of the following arguments is invalid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$[p \land (p \rightarrow q)] \rightarrow q$ Valid

$[(p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s) \land (p \lor r)] \rightarrow (q \lor s)$ Invalid

$[(q \rightarrow r) \land (s \rightarrow q)] \rightarrow (s \rightarrow r)$ Valid

$[(p \lor q) \land (q \rightarrow r)]  \rightarrow \lnot r$ Valid

Am I correct? I have a hard time with logic.

Comment: seems 1-3 are right and 4 is wrong so you have 2 mistakes, in #2 and #4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second one is valid: you know you have $p$ or $r$. Well, if you have $p$, then you have $q$, and so you have $q \lor s$. On the other hand, if you have $r$, then you have $s$, and so again you have $q \lor s$. So, you definitely have $q \lor s$.  This reasoning follows an important proof technique called a Proof by Cases

Fourth one is invalid. Counterexample: If $p, q, r$ are all true, then the left side is true but the right side is false.